# Ajax control not working properly.

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have used ajax control in asp.net c# application

```
 <div class="uploadfiles">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
<asp:FileUpload ID="file_upload" class="multi" runat="server" />
   <br /> 
   <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="btnUpload_Click"/>
   <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>

     <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
     </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in .cs file

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
            if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/") + fileName);
                lblMessage.Text += fileName + "Saved Successfully<br>";
                HyperLink dynamHyperLink = new HyperLink();
                dynamHyperLink.Text = fileName.ToString() + "Saved Successfully<br>";
                // hyperlnk.Attributes.Add("href", Server.MapPath("/UploadFiles/") + fileName);
                dynamHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "~/UploadFiles/" + fileName;

                Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamHyperLink);
                //lblMessage.Text= "<a href=" + "/UploadFiles/" + fileName +">"+fileName+"</a>";
            }
        }
    }
```

When I Click on upload button it's not executing the `btnupload_Click()` event and doesn't display uploaded files in `Panel1` control.

Please help me!!!

Comment: File upload control not works inside update panel

Answer (score 0):

use `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />` instead of AsyncPostBackTrigger on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Take `FileUpload`

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="file_upload" class="multi" runat="server" />
```

outside the update panel and add `EventName` parameter to this

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
```

like  this

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" EventName="Click" />
```

Comment: It's incorrect, Asynchronous post-back doesn't work for Fileupload inside the Update Panel control..

Comment: true.. changed my answer